# How can I do: var value = foo(bar); Where foo a function that looks up the value through a JSON request

Tags: jquery, ajax, function

Coming from a PHP background I run into this kind of problem often when I'm programming with JavaScript & jQuery.  I need a function that needs to take a variable and do a server lookup to get a status result back.

Rather than having to repeat the same code (which I am doing now and my boss dislikes) in 4 different places, I would prefer it to be a function I can call from anywhere.

The actual code is a lot more complex, I stripped it down to the basic concept for the purposes of this question.

I tried using "async: false" so that the function would wait for the ajax call to complete before returning, but it didn't work.

The solution likely is to use a Callback function.  How exactly does this work and how would I need to structure my code to achieve this universally in different locations of my app (code)?

```
var sample = "ABC12345";
var samplestatus = getStatus(sample);
console.log("!!!!" + samplestatus + "!!!!");        

function getStatus(samplenumber) {  
    var jsonurl =  "lookup.php?s="+samplenumber;
    $.ajax({
        url: jsonurl,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(data1) {
            var s_status;
            if (typeof(data1[0]) !== 'undefined') {
                var data = data1[0];
                s_status = data.STATUS;
                console.log("Sample " + samplenumber + " has a status of "+s_status);
                return(s_status);
            } else {
                return(0);  
            }
        }
    });     
}
```

The output:

```
Sample ABC12345 has a status of COMPLETED
!!!!undefined!!!!
```

Comment: You need to return the ajax request.  The issue is that the function itself isnt returning anything. it is executing code therein.  So you would want to look at Promises, and develop a promise, and then await it.

Comment: @Fallenreaper thank you. Looks like Ken Yoro Ko did something similar below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return from the function you call.

```
function getStatus(samplenumber) {
    var jsonurl  ="lookup.php?s="+samplenumber;

    return $.ajax({
        url: jsonurl,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(data1) {
            var s_status;
            if (typeof(data1[0]) !== 'undefined') {
                var data = data1[0];
                s_status = data.STATUS;
                console.log("Sample " + samplenumber + " has a status of "+s_status);
                return s_status;
            } else {
                return 0;  
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This works, but one thing I noticed is you still have the 2 returns in there, return s_status and return 0.  If you're returning the whole thing are those 2 calls still required?

Comment: @MichaelFever Success is just a function call, just like error, and done.  (look up AJAX Requests). As long as the success call is fired, that function executes, and will do whatever you want, just like any other function.  His is doing some status validation.